# Query one category name from multiple post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, categories

I've got a problem with a query. I've got 4 different post_type.
I would like to retrieve the posts from all post type from one category named 'une'. But it shows only post type from two post type => spectacles and post.

Here is my code :

```
<?php 
query_posts(array(
'post_type' => array('post','videos','photos','spectacles'),
'showposts' => -1,
'category_name' => 'une',
)
); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It is like `category_name` doesn't work for my query.

Comment: Please check again that the `category` taxonomy as well as category **une** is associated with all the post types and posts. I think the `category` taxonomy is not associated with all the post types.

Comment: The post type are all registered like this
`register_post_type( 'photos',
  array(
   'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Photos' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Photo' )
   ),
  'public' => true,
  'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag'),
  'has_archive' => true,
  'supports' => array('title','content','editor','excerpt','thumbnail'),
  )
 );`

Comment: Can you see the default post `category` taxonomy at `photos` post type at backend dashboard ?

Comment: Yes ! For all the post type !

Comment: @the_dramatist i found the solution !!! Thank you very much !!!

Comment: Wow... That's good news. Then post the solution here so that other people also can get benefited.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem, i add this to the functions.php

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
  if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
     'post', 'nav_menu_item', 'spectacles','historique','photos','videos'
        ));
      return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```